# How to apply the changes from a remote branch again with git pull?

Tags: git, github

Not sure I formulate my question properly.
I consider myself still a novice with git/source control.

I forked the repository of a static website theme on github (https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) and started by own blog from it.
I have been working with it for a while and everything worked.

Recently I wanted to pull the last changes from mmistakes/minimal-mistakes repository. I usually just do:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes.git
git pull upstream master
Then resolve the conflicts and push
```

However in the last version of mmistakes/minimal-mistakes i noticed some issues with the Search feature. So i looked for a way to revert my changes, and did something like:

```
git revert <commit sha>
Then resolve the conflicts and push
```

This worked but i realized the Search feature was related to something else :(
Now i want to pull the changes from the last version again by doing:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes.git
git pull upstream master
```

But it tells me:

```
From https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]        master     -> upstream/master
Already up to date.
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All changes from the `upstream/master` are in your repository, there is nothing to pull. If you want to undo your revert there are two ways: either remove the revert commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~ # I assume here that HEAD is the revert commit
git push --force-with-lease origin/master
```

or revert the revert:

```
git revert HEAD # I assume here that HEAD is the revert commit
git push origin/master
```